# Latest BIOS for B450M PRO4 Ryzen 7 2700 CPU

Tags: bios

I built a new PC few months ago, but monitor doesn't start after Windows-10 wakes from the sleep mode. I have MoBo BIOS version P3.60. Anyone come across this issue and have recommendation on how to fix ? BIOS upgrade ? ASROCK website has latest BIOS version 4.90 but also suggests not to upgrade the BIOS for Summit Ridge or Pinnacle CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running P4.60 BIOS with my Ryzen 7 2700 CPU. Wake from sleep is working fine, although I rarely use it. The monitor is connected to an AMD RX580 GPU via Display Port.

I am considering updating the BIOS to the latest version (4.90) as I am experiencing some instability (could be an issue with my memory modules and the XMP profile that I am using).

EDIT: Updated the BIOS today to the latest version, ran Memtest on different XMP settings, no errors, no crashes. As the stability issues were quite sporadic I will reserve my judgement for later, but, so far so good.

Comment: I decided to drop the BIOS version to 3.5.  That seems to have done the trick.  For the last two weeks, I have been running without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it running. I am also happy with how 4.90 has been running so far. Here is to many more years of no issues with this MoBo and CPU combo.